# Adding or Forcing Line Break after div

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that hold some anchor tags as shown below. And also a `<hr>` tag to segment my page. however even using the div as a *block* element wouldn't force the `<hr>` element to start on a new line rather it aligns the `<hr>` next to the div.

how can i resolve this?

```
<div id="inner">
    <div id="headerBlock">
        <a href='.actorgroup' id='346' onclick='return displayactorgroupFunc(this.id);'>Actor2</a>
        <span class='rowNumber2'> | </span>
        <a href='.actorgroup' id='15201' onclick='return displayactorgroupFunc(this.id);'>Actor1</a>
    </div>
</div><hr/>
```

Css:

```
#headerBlock{
    display: block;
}
#inner {
     padding:10px;
     display:block;
     float: left;
}
#inner a{
     display:inline-block;
     padding-left:20px;
     line-height:20px;
     color:#808000;
     font-size:14px;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: display:block for <a> tag? is this what you need?

Comment: my bad, i just edited the question @math3w, i want a new line after the div(inner). do you have any idea?

Comment: would <br><hr> work?

Comment: try clear:both; to <hr>

Comment: try this   http://jsfiddle.net/gr0ope1s/

Comment: @Math3w it worked. you can add your answer so i can confirm its correctness. thanks

Comment: @Manube, that what i did before and it never worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `float:left` is causing the problem. Apply `clear:both;` to `<hr>` will do:

```
hr{ clear:both; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/mw81e8Lq/)**

Answer (score 5):

Find below the solution with HTML (CSS will remain same). I've modified code for brevity.

```
<div id="inner">
    <div id="headerBlock">
        <a>Actor2</a>
        <span class='rowNumber2'> | </span>
        <a>Actor1</a>
    </div>
</div>
<hr style="clear:both;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this style

```
.rowNumber2{
    display : block;
}
```

Comment: the line break is for the <hr> element. i want the hr element after the div-inner

Answer (score 0):

None of this helped.  For my purpose it was as simple as adding.

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

This tells the browser to treat the div/object it's applied to as a single object that shouldn't split across multiple pages.